# Unable to request a token from the Twitter OAuth API using ES6 Fetch

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, react-native

I'm attempting to gain a token from Twitter's API using a POST request to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token with ES6's Fetch API in React Native.

This is the code I have:

```
fetch('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Oauth: {
      oauth_callback: 'reactnativechirp://callback',
      oauth_consumer_key: keys.consumerKey,
      oauth_nonce: nonce,
      oauth_signature: 'Pc%2BMLdv028fxCErFyi8KXFM%2BddU%3D',
      oauth_signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
      oauth_timestamp: epoch,
      oauth_version: '1.0'
    }
  }
})
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((json) => {
  console.log(json);
})
```

oauth_nonce is set to a nonce variable, which I generate on the fly as a random twenty-character string.

oauth_timestamp is set to the current Unix epoch time by using `new Date().getTime()`

This request is being made in `componentDidMount()`, and I receive an error object logged to the console with `code: 215, message: 'Bad Authentication data.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This may help you https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/application-only

Comment: @Jickson I'm not looking for just Application-Only access.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the old twitter api. You can use https://github.com/BoyCook/TwitterJSClient and https://github.com/aivis/user-stream libraries to authenticate and work with the twitter api.
If not, you can also study up on how oauth works with the latest twitter API version 1.1 [here](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth)